# Safely catch a 'Allowed memory size exhausted' error in PHP

Tags: php, memory

I have a gateway script that returns JSON back to the client.
In the script I use [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to catch errors and still have a formatted return.

It is subject to 'Allowed memory size exhausted' errors, but rather than increase the memory limit with something like [ini_set('memory_limit', '19T')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), I just want to return that the user should try something else because it used to much memory.

Are there any good ways to catch fatal errors?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146171/409279) suggests, you can use `register_shutdown_function()` to register a callback that'll check `error_get_last()`.

You'll still have to manage the output generated from the offending code, whether by the `@` (*shut up*) operator, or `ini_set('display_errors', false)`

```
ini_set('display_errors', false);

error_reporting(-1);

set_error_handler(function($code, $string, $file, $line){
        throw new ErrorException($string, null, $code, $file, $line);
    });

register_shutdown_function(function(){
        $error = error_get_last();
        if(null !== $error)
        {
            echo 'Caught at shutdown';
        }
    });

try
{
    while(true)
    {
        $data .= str_repeat('#', PHP_INT_MAX);
    }
}
catch(\Exception $exception)
{
    echo 'Caught in try/catch';
}
```

When run, this outputs `Caught at shutdown`. Unfortunately, the `ErrorException` exception object isn't thrown because the fatal error triggers script termination, subsequently caught only in the shutdown function.

You can check the `$error` array in the shutdown function for details on the cause, and respond accordingly. One suggestion could be reissuing the request back against your web application (*at a different address, or with different parameters of course*) and return the captured response.

I recommend keeping `error_reporting()` high (*a value of `-1`*) though, and using (*as others have suggested*) error handling for everything else with `set_error_handler()` and `ErrorException`.

Comment: +1 for general aptitude in the face of wanton incorrectness :)

Comment: In case this is a problem for anyone else, it's worth bearing in mind that register_shutdown_function loses your call stack when it's called. So you can't really use it to work out *where* your memory error happened.

Comment: @ChrisRae  if you've got xdebug enhabled, xdebug_get_function_stack(), is a debug_backtrace alternative that will have the entire trace

Comment: I'm scratching my head, I have a class method (laravel), in which I call shutdown on first line of function. memory runs out but the funstion never gets called and doesn't echos `caught at shutdown`.  I copy pasted exact code above before try catch lines. Any help? if I place this in index.php the root file, then it works

Comment: (shut up) operator XD

Answer (score 52):

If you need to execute business code when this error happens (logging, backup of the context for future debugs, emailing or such), registering a shutdown function is not enough: you should free memory in a way.

One solution is to allocate some emergency memory somewhere:

```
public function initErrorHandler()
{
    // This storage is freed on error (case of allowed memory exhausted)
    $this->memory = str_repeat('*', 1024 * 1024);

    register_shutdown_function(function()
    {
        $this->memory = null;
        if ((!is_null($err = error_get_last())) && (!in_array($err['type'], array (E_NOTICE, E_WARNING))))
        {
           // $this->emergencyMethod($err);
        }
    });
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I thought this sounded completely stupid when I read it - I thought "surely some kind of cleanup would happen between when PHP runs out of memory and when it calls the shutdown function, and you wouldn't have to worry about that... ". I was very wrong. Thank you so much for taking the time to post this - very helpful!

Comment: One thing to know is that your check `array (E_NOTICE, E_WARNING)` will actually catch depreciation notices and other unwanted minor issues. Some cases, you may want to rewrite to remove the ! negation and replace it with `in_array($err['type'], array (E_ERROR))`

Comment: Fascinating. Working.

Comment: A slightly faster way to allocate memory is e.g. `new SplFixedArray(65536);`. Each empty array element consumes 16 bytes on my system.

Comment: Amazing and awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

While @alain-tiemblo solution works perfectly, I put this script to show how you can reserve some memory in a php script, out of object scope.

#### Short Version

```
// memory is an object and it is passed by reference
function shutdown($memory) {
    // unsetting $memory does not free up memory
    // I also tried unsetting a global variable which did not free up the memory
    unset($memory->reserve);
}

$memory = new stdClass();
// reserve 3 mega bytes
$memory->reserve = str_repeat('❤', 1024 * 1024);

register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $memory);
```

#### Full Sample Script

```
<?php

function getMemory(){
    return ((int) (memory_get_usage() / 1024)) . 'KB';
}

// memory is an object and it is passed by reference
function shutdown($memory) {
    echo 'Start Shut Down: ' . getMemory() . PHP_EOL;

    // unsetting $memory does not free up memory
    // I also tried unsetting a global variable which did not free up the memory
    unset($memory->reserve);

    echo 'End Shut Down: ' . getMemory() . PHP_EOL;
}

echo 'Start: ' . getMemory() . PHP_EOL;

$memory = new stdClass();
// reserve 3 mega bytes
$memory->reserve = str_repeat('❤', 1024 * 1024);

echo 'After Reserving: ' . getMemory() . PHP_EOL;

unset($memory);

echo 'After Unsetting: ' . getMemory() . PHP_EOL;

$memory = new stdClass();
// reserve 3 mega bytes
$memory->reserve = str_repeat('❤', 1024 * 1024);

echo 'After Reserving again: ' . getMemory() . PHP_EOL;

// passing $memory object to shut down function
register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $memory);
```

And the output would be:

```
Start: 349KB
After Reserving: 3426KB
After Unsetting: 349KB
After Reserving again: 3426KB
Start Shut Down: 3420KB
End Shut Down: 344KB
```

Comment: A slightly faster way to allocate memory is e.g. `new SplFixedArray(65536);`. Each empty array element consumes 16 bytes on my system.

Answer (score 9):

you could get the size of the memory already consumed by the process by using this function memory_get_peak_usage documentations are at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php I think it would be easier if you could add a condition to redirect or stop the process before the memory limit is almost reached by the process. :)

Comment: Indeed, this is a way of catching the error before it happens.   Allows for one to save status information on the  ongoing task and possibly even resume it once redirected.

Comment: +1 -- I agree, managing the issue before it becomes an error is likely the best solution (*and yields the most robust handling options*) however, error "handling" for fatal errors has it's benefits too. A hybrid solution, managing memory status when possible, handling fatals when necessary, is likely the best approach to employ.

Comment: Sure, but script memory allocation errors are often too hard to predict, as PHP doesn't generally engage in smalltalk with us about its internal memory business, so we know little about what's going to be the memory cost of calling external libraries, DB queries, image manipulation, or just using big multi-dimensional arrays etc. At what exact load level to start the "preventive panicking", can only be guessed. (*Sometimes* still quite well, nevertheless.)

Comment: I came on similar problem of memory allocation but in different situation: uploaded image resizing some 10MB of jpeg grow fast to more than 100MB on RAM. i used this formula to apreciate the RAM needed: $width * $height * 4 * 1.5 + 1048576 from this site [link](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/allocate-memory-on-the-fly-with-php-for-image-resizing/). I dont know if it's optimal but it seems to work well (~70MB computed for some ~60MB really allocated by the image)