# Why is this mysql query requiring the PDO::prepare call twice in php7 (but not in php8)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php-7, php-8

I have a simple piece of code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

This outputs `0` when run with PHP7.
However, this is the wrong/unexpected result.
The expected result is `15`.
If I run the above code in PHP8 I get the expected result.

If I duplicate the line `$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);`, as in the code below, I then get the correct value in PHP7.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

My connection is established in the following way:

```
$this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8',
    DB_USER, DB_PASS,
    [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8;SET time_zone = '" . TIMEZONE . "'"]);
```

Clearly something is wrong as the second prepare shouldn't be necessary, but I don't know where to start.
Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

PHP versions I'm using specifically:
PHP 7.2.34
PHP 8.0.8

#### Clarification

I would like the user rows returned (not the number - that's just to show the problem) - but with PHP7 I get no rows, with PHP8 I get all the requested/existing rows.

#### Clarification #2

Yes, sorry, I was trying to provide a minimal working example.
I do fetch and iterate through the users.
For simplicity though, I'm currently just checking the number of rows/users returned:

```
$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo count($users);
```

The use of `rowCount()` was meant to simplify the issue.

The MySQL driver versions are:
`mysql (mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407`
`mysql (mysqlnd 8.0.13)`

#### Clarification #3

`$stmt->execute();` does return false. **My bad - sorry.**

However, looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604217/what-to-do-on-php-pdo-execute-returns-false), the output of `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

I've added the following to my DB connection but I'm not getting any more information than the above.

```
$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

#### Clarification 4

False trail as "$pdo->errorInfo() refers to the last statement that was successfully executed" https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438685/1489538.

Comment: The backend (mysqlnd vs libmysql) or sql emulation state (and MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS) are probably more relevant than version number superstition.

Comment: This might depend on the database driver version, I suppose? The manual has some user comments about similar issues, like this one, https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#113608, _"In some drivers rowCount() only works when using the prepare() with PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL"_ - maybe a second `prepare` call has a similar effect, dunno.

Comment: See I get the number of rows returned with only one prepare using 7.2.34 and 8.0.13

Comment: Does `$stmt->execute()` return false when you get no rows?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, yes it does return false. Thanks for suggesting this. I've added clarifications to the post as the error code is not helpful.

Comment: This may be the path to explore for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813911/php-pdo-error-number-00000-when-query-is-correct

Comment: Please reproduce the problem on https://phpize.online/ because we need to know the exact steps that need to be taken to reproduce this.