# PHPUnit integration test for fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: phpunit, php-7, monolog

I would like to test, if my application logs the Fatal error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size exhausted
```

to my monolog handler file. I would like to write an integration test for that.
The problem is that when I trigger an error, PHPUnit will stop.

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function testMemoryLimitExhaustedLogToMonolog(): void
{
    // set memory limit 100mb
    ini_set('memory_limit', '100M');

    while(true) {
        $memoryExhaustingArray[] = 1;
    }
    $this->assertThatMyLogFileHasCatchedTheOutOfMemoryException();
}
```

Is there a way to test a fatal out of memory error in PHP7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is no way of testing this fatal error, because PHPUnit crashes when it is out of memory. This error triggers script termination and can not be caught:

[Safely catch a 'Allowed memory size exhausted' error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440439/safely-catch-a-allowed-memory-size-exhausted-error-in-php)