# Can we check memory usage while execution in php and failed the job if memory reaches to 80% or more or before browser crash

Tags: php, linux, out-of-memory

I am facing an issue running a job which is sometimes using memory more than expected and now i want to implement a script which failed the execution when memory reaches to 80% or more.

Comment: Look into using ulimit.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the memory limit by adding the following line -

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

The value is in bytes. The job/script will terminate with an error if the allocated memory is exhausted. More details related to ini_set can be found at - [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: thanks, but i need to inform the user before memory exhausted (equal to or more than 80%) and I will show them a custom error.

Comment: Maybe combining with this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581958/7362396