# Allowed Memory Size Exhausted Error instead of Undefined Error

Tags: php, php-7

I've recently installed PHP 7.0.10 on my server and discovered and strange behavior :

Instead of throwing me an `undefined variable` or `undefined index` error, PHP throws me an `allowed memory exhausted error`.

Memory limit was increased in php.ini file, nothing changed.
Have you any idea why this happens, and how to resolve it ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Not sure if you are using IIS, if so, maybe you can check the buffer size limit ? To be honest with you, I'm really not sure if this can help.

Comment: Nope, i'm using Apache

Comment: Or maybe this can help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318858/how-to-recover-from-a-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-exhausted

Comment: The problem isn't the `allowed memory size exhausted error`, it's why the wrong error is thrown..

Comment: What memory limit have you set in php.ini file?

Comment: memory limit is set to 128M