# How to catch this exception and want to send mail alert with this error

Tags: php, laravel

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 88 bytes) in /var/www/html/Xogonet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 323

I tried to catch this error in **Laravel exception handler class**.but couldn't able to.

also i tried with using **try / catch** blocks

```
try {
    $query = "some select query which give huge data";
}catch (Exception $e){
    Log::info('Error '. $e);
}
```

Please get me out from this issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318858/how-to-recover-from-a-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-exhausted see here may help you

Comment: i think you missed the backslash "\". use it as `catch (\Exception $e)`